# How add header with .NetOffice library

Tags: c#, ms-word, netoffice

I'm using [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) to create Word documents.

There is little documentation and I'm struggling to add a header. Can anybody help?

Comment: What do you mean by _header_? If you mean a matter of font size/color/boldness/ecc.. you can play with the `Selection` property of a `Word.Application` object

Comment: like add a header to document so it appears on each page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `Word.Section.Headers` property, in the example below I've put an image right-aligned on the page header

```
    foreach (Word.Section section in newDocument.Sections)
        {
            string picturePath = @"D:\Desktop\test.png";
            section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(picturePath);
            section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
        }
```

To add some text use:

```
    foreach (Word.Section section in newDocument.Sections)
       section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Text = "TEST";
```

Hope this helps to investigate further.